# Delete AKS deployment's running pod on regular basis (Job)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have been struggling for some time to figure out how to accomplish the following:
I want to delete running pod on Azure Kubernetes Service cluster on scheduled basis, so that it respawns from deployment. This is required that application re-reads configuration files stored on shared storage and shared with other application.

I have found out that Kubernetes **[Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#what-is-a-job)** might be handy to accomplish this, but there is some but.
I cant figure how can I select corresponding pod related to my deployment as it adds random string to the deployment name, i.e

```
deployment-name-546fcbf44f-wckh4
```

Using selectors to get my pod doesnt succeed as there is not such operator like LIKE

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector metadata.name=deployment-name
```

No resources found

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the official docs one way of doing this would be like so:

```
pods=$(kubectl get pods --selector=job-name=pi --output=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}')
echo $pods
```

you'd need to modify `job-name` to match your job name

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#running-an-example-job